# What's the difference between the W3 and xmlsoap.org schemas?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

When creating a wsdl file in eclipse it sets the name spaces to:

```
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Why exactly is it using schemas.xmlsoap.org and not the relevant w3 schemas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am confused about SOAP namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403980/i-am-confused-about-soap-namespaces)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "schemas.xmlsoap.org" namespaces are for SOAP 1.1.  See the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383489) for more info.

The "w3c.org" namespaces are used for [SOAP 1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part0-20070427/#L1157).  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), SOAP did not become a W3C recommendation until version 1.2.

Trivia:  the domain "xmlsoap.org" is owned by Microsoft (try running a whois).

**EDIT:**  It turns out this question is a duplicate of [I am confused about SOAP namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403980/i-am-confused-about-soap-namespaces)

Comment: Ah I did not find that question when googling. Thanks though. I voted to close my own question, assuming that's proper.