# Soap version mismatch - how to create and accept older standard?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm having to create a web service to a schema provided by a third party and having great difficulty in doing so!

One issue I'm having is their envelope is sent using:

```
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
```

I get a "soap:VersionMismatch" error.

Sent using the following works fine:

```
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
OR
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
```

**Q:** How can I create the web service/configure it to accept their soap envelope? Is that an older standard?

Comment: That namespace URI is neither SOAP 1.1 nor SOAP 1.2. It looks like it came from someone who read the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_envelope.asp) site. I don't think there's anything you can do other than suggest the sender follow international standards.

Comment: Thanks John. I have seen a few examples out on the net using same although more than likely same reason! Few queries. **(1)** Is the standard to use the namespace at xmlsoap.org? **(2)** Why does the error response from my .Net web service suggest an upgrade to the 2003/05 w3 version? **(3)** The web services they expose expect and use this namespace, meaning it is achievable somehow if one wished to _break_ standards!?!

Comment: Honestly, their mistake is so large that your company should truly consider not doing business with them. It's not rocket science, and I can't imagine what their excuse is for being incompetent. The SOAP 1.2 standard would be the one to follow if there's a choice, otherwise SOAP 1.1. They seem to be imagining standards.

Comment: Just come across this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403980/i-am-confused-about-soap-namespaces). Is the answer on this wrong? What namespaces SHOULD be used for a 1.1 or 1.2 envelope?

Comment: That answer is correct. The bad one is the "2001" namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous commenting, appreciated! What is the best way to close on this? The answer is your first comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That namespace URI is neither SOAP 1.1 nor SOAP 1.2. It looks like it came from someone who read the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_envelope.asp) site. I don't think there's anything you can do other than suggest the sender follow international standards.