# SOAP1.1 or SOAP1.2

Tags: wcf, soap, gsoap

I have two request messages generated by gSOAP library:

**1**

```
POST http://localhost:8998/Service1.svc/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8998
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.8
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"
Content-Length: 536
Connection: close
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService2" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetData><ns1:value>55</ns1:value></ns1:GetData></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**2**

```
POST http://localhost:8998/Service1.svc/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8998
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 538
Connection: close
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService2" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetData><ns1:value>55</ns1:value></ns1:GetData></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What kind of messages they are `SOAP 1.1` or `SOAP 1.2` ?

First message was formated by proxy class that was generated by wsdl2h and soapcpp2 by default. This message request failes. Second message was generated by proxy with changed namespace inside of it:

from

```
{"SOAP-ENV", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", NULL},
```

to

```
{"SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",NULL},
```

And it works fine. Why I need to change namespace to make it work? Why gSOAP tools can't generate correct namespace?

WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8998/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8998/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8998/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService2"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContract"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContractResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IService1">
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Service1">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8998/Service1.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am confused about SOAP namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403980/i-am-confused-about-soap-namespaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403980/i-am-confused-about-soap-namespaces) states that SOAP 1.1 uses this namespace:

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
```

while SOAP 1.2 uses this namespace:

```
http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
```

Your *first* message appears therefore to be from SOAP 1.2, while your *second* message appears to be from SOAP 1.1.  Since your first message is failing, and the second passes, it would seem that you are using a SOAP 1.1 compliant service.

Comment: I made mistake while mixing "from" "to". WSDL added

Comment: But is it SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2 ?

Comment: And which attribute defines SOAP version?

Comment: From what I can tell, the version is implicit in the namespace chosen for the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times you can know that the version of SOAP request is 1.2, when you see

`Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="address"`

SOAP 1.1 uses `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`